# Crear modelo de datos donde el usuario definido los campos y tipos de campo

Tags: mysql, modelos

Voy a tratar de explicar lo que quiero conseguir.

La idea es que los usuarios puedan crear tablas definiendo los campos que estas van a tener y el tipo de campo (string, integer, boolean, enum,..). Esta definición la resuelvo con una tabla con dos campos:

name - almacena el nombre del campo
type - almacena el tipo de campo

El problema es como definir ahora la tabla, que contenga, los valores que el usuario introduzca en estos campos (sin necesidad de crear una tabla por cada definición).

En esta imagen se puede ver las dos tablas que he creado, una con la definición de la tabla y otra con los campos de la misma. Me faltaría esa tercera, que contendria los valores que se hayan definido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Siempre puedes guardar esos campos o configuraciones variables en un campo de tipo LONGTEXT y almacenar un json dentro con la dicha configuración específica de cada lista. Luego lo único que tendrías es que leer el json y escribir en pantalla los diferentes campos almacenados